# Regex for not including the contain of a closed curly braces in Java

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Please help me to solve this in java.

```
input string = <V2>UTM_Source:google|UTM_Medium:cpc|UTM_Campaign:{Core|IN|Desktop|BMM|Top Cities|TS}|
UTM_Content:{Compare Car Insurance}|UTM_Term:
```

I want to split with "|" but not the inside contain of curly braces
So the output will be:

```
<V2>UTM_Source:google
UTM_Medium:cpc
UTM_Campaign:{Core|IN|Desktop|BMM|Top Cities|TS}
UTM_Content:{Compare Car Insurance}
UTM_Term:
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I had a pattern to find "|" and the other to find inside contain of {} braces. Just wanted to join them using and with a negation, but it didn't work that's why I posted. :).

Comment: In future, please post your attempts too along with your issue(s) to get proper answers quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, you want to match the *entire* `{...}` sequences all at the same time, or in other words, treat them as a single character within your regular expression: `\{.*?\}`  Using this fragment as the first choice in an alternation with a single "regular non pipe" character, and then letting that whole thing repeat, we avoid spurious matches inside the curly brackets:

`((?:\{.*?\}|[^|])+)\|`

or as Sven points out, you don't even need that last | or the capturing group:

`(?:\{.*?\}|[^|])+`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/5THEWj/3/)

Comment: When you leave out the trailing `\|`, the full match is already the desired group. [https://regex101.com/r/5THEWj/4](https://regex101.com/r/5THEWj/4)